# How to use numpy where to select items in a matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

For a simple Q-learning program I am reading the reward matrix is R. I am trying to understand why the `[1]` is at the end of the statement for `av_act` (available actions).

```
def available_actions(state):
    current_state_row = R[state,]
    av_act = np.where(current_state_row >= 0)[1]
    return av_act
```